# What bias it would be called?

Tags: fallacies, cognitive-bias, decision-theory

When someone thinks that he is being biased towards selecting option 1 (between option 1 and option 2) and hence he switched into option 2 where his correct decision would actually be selecting option 1.

**Which biash he is having?** In other words, what is the name of the bias when someone becomes biased against a bias?

Lets say I am feeling that most people are biased for patriarchy and thats why I should be unbiased unlike most people. Hence, I decided to join feminist movement and eventually I became biased against patriarchy (or biased for feminism i.e. started hating men). Now is there any name of such bias? Bias arose for avoiding opposite bias.

Comment: Some call it [overcompensation bias](https://www.reddit.com/r/thebayesianconspiracy/comments/4riv4f/overcompensation_bias/). I do not think this is an established term, but talk of overcompensation in more specific contexts is widespread in academic literature, see e.g. [Goh's thesis The Structure of Overcompensation](https://repository.library.northeastern.edu/files/neu:cj82qb48f/fulltext.pdf) for the case of anti-gay bias.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 2 options, and the known bias for option 1 is the only known bias from your end, then it seems rational and deontic you choose option 2 assuming you do want to get rid of your bias/prejudice. It's just unlucky if it turns out option 2 is not good either, but it's moot with your deontic choice before. If you later regret your choice simply because of the unwanted result (meaning you're switching to be consequential not deontological after the result), then you likely form a new [Hindsight bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindsight_bias) but not necessarily so in your described case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May be I couldn’t express well what I am looking for. Lets say I am feeling that most people are biased for patriarchy and thats why I should be unbiased unlike most people. Hence, I decided to join feminist movement and eventually I became biased against patriarchy (or biased for feminism i.e. started hating men). Now is there any name of such bias? Bias arose for avoiding opposite bias. Thanks.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan One certainly may have many different biases simultaneously. In your ideal case you just gradually eliminate an old bias, and gradually acquire a new bias which is very likely in reality. Bias are usually for something A (implicitly against those ~A). If your bias shifts to ~A, then you can call it opposite bias of the original, but usually it just becomes a new bias whose generic name you can choose from the list here (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias)